# Getting Facebook friends of friends in asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

I am creating facebook integrated asp.net web application.I am getting the friends of

logged in user in a grid. I also have the profile pic of the friends. Now i want that

clicking on the pic of a friend should display friends of that friends

(lets say, logged in user is ABC. And he has two friends xyz and def. Now i want that

clicking on the pic of xyz should display the friends of xyz in the same grid.

Can anyone provide me javascript for that or is there any other way?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Isha.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this.  You can not get a list of friends of a friend of the user that authenticated the application.  That's a mouthful! :P let me try simplify - 
Lets say you authenticate an application - and allow that application to view your friend list.  For the sake of this example let us say that I am in your friend list - and the application has now found me to be a friend of yours.   The application can not see MY friend list because I have not authenticated the application.   This is an issue of privacy and it is simple not possible with the facebook API (and shouldn't be possible)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems about that:

1- Facebook see that behaviour like spam and in his politics is prohibited to do that.

2- To see your friendos, the aplication needs permissions like **user_friends**, and if i am not autenticated with the app, it cant get my access token and cant ask for this permisions, so the app cant look my friends.

Another tip is that there is not a good idea to make a questions saying what you want and asking for the solution like

> "Can anyone provide me javascript for that or is there any other way?"

Is better if you expose what you did, the comunity correct your errors and we camo to a solution...